# What does the word “s***storm” mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, nouns, offensive-language

The definition of *shitstorm* in New Oxford American Dictionary:

> a situation marked by violent controversy.

The definition in Wikipedia:

> a vulgar dysphemism for a chaotic and unpleasant situation.

I want to know what exactly a *shitstorm* consists of. Does it include a wrestling scene, or more of a disputing situation?

Comment: Wrestling? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: It means a whole lot of bad things happening at once. It is not usually used for a particular physical situation like wrestling unless the wrestling or fighting is one example of how things are going badly. A shitstorm may result in a physical altercation, but the altercation is not itself a shitstorm. A synonym (not exact) is a 'clusterfuck'.

Comment: Why would a downvoted question elicit so many questions and comments?

Answer (score 7):

A *shitstorm* does not necessarily include either a physical altercation, or a dispute.  Instead, a *shitstorm* is any extraordinarily chaotic situation where there is no possible positive outcome.

I don't have a source to back up my claim, but I suspect that "shitstorm" is derived from the idiom "The shit has hit the fan."

Comment: yeah，I know it as "when the shit hits the fan".

Answer (score 4):

In British English, most likely the equivalent of "a dog's breakfast".

Comment: mmm... breakfast.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: @Mitch sounds like a pretty *crappy* breakfast to me